# Accessing a single value using foreach loop in view coming from the view model in durandal

Tags: foreach, viewmodel, durandal

I have a Project Title, what I want to do is when I click on the title, all of the associated activities are displayed, I have an API, which brings all the associated activities,API is developed in YII framework, the API is called in view model and all the activities are accessible in the view through foreach loop, what I want to do is to display a single activity a time, at the moment when i click on project title, all activites are displayed, I want one activitiy to be displayed when clicked once. Please if any one can answer.

this is my viewModel...

```
 function fetchProjectActivities() {
     var self = this;
     // this.current_activities.length=0;
     dataservice.projectactivities(self.id()).then(function (data) {
         //self.current_activities().clear();
         for (x in data) {
             self.current_activities.push(new Activity(data[x].activity.id, data[x].user_id, data[x].user.first_name, data[x].user.last_name, data[x].activity.message, new Date(data[x].create_date), data[x].time_spent, data[x].tags, null, data[x].activity.status,
             self.name()));
         }
         console.log("aaa" + self);
     });
 }
```

and this is my view...

```
<div class="grid-item project-item clearfix">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12"><h3>
        <div data-bind="foreach:projects">
            <div data-bind="foreach: current_activities">
               <span data-bind="text: title()"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is the function which gets invoked when I click on Projects title.

Project Name: `<a data-bind="click: $root.fetchProjectActivities"><span data-bind="text: name()">`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of thing that I can see.

1. there is a rogue `<h3>` tag in the html that will cause grief with knockoutjs. that will need to be closed or removed.
2. the for loop in the view model really should be `for (var x in data) {...}` otherwise you will end up with x declared as a variable on the global scope.

Now to cycle through the activities of the project, what you are effectively doing is paging through current_activities array, one at a time.  You will need to keep track of the currently selected activity and a way to go forward with each click and a list of all the activities.

so you will need a pager view model.  there is a very basic one on the [knockoutjs site](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html) that you could use and modify to your needs.

Comment: Corrected both the things :( Didnt solved the problem

Comment: can you add more of the view model as what you currently have is very limited. in the html above you reference projects and current_activities.  these don't appear in the viewmodel